# How do you map an http JSON response to an interface in Angular/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm simply trying to make this stupid thing understand that the
"sounds" value is an integer array and not a string array.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying:

```
export interface Startup {
  Tunings: Tuning;
}

export interface Tuning {
  n: string | null;
  sounds: (number)[] ;
 
}

//blah blah

go() {
 return new Promise<Startup>((resolve, reject) => {
      const promise = this.http.get<Startup>("http://localhost:5555/startup").toPromise();
      promise.then((data: Startup)=>{
        console.log(data);

        resolve(data);
      }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log("Promise rejected with " + JSON.stringify(error));
        reject(error);
      });

    });
}
```

It's on the server looking like this:

```
{"n": "E A D G B E (Guitar Standard)",  "sounds": [40, 45, 50, 55, 59, 64]}
```

console.logging the response looks like this:

```
{"n": "E A D G B E (Guitar Standard)",  "sounds": ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Comment: TypeScript **does not exist** at runtime, types are erased in compilation (see e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25401 for a bunch of related issues). If you want to process the response you need to do so *in JavaScript*, but if what you're actually receiving doesn't contain the data you need, there's no way to do that.

Comment: @FrancescoLisandro that will not make any difference at all. The parentheses there don't do anything, so neither will removing them, and again _TypeScript doesn't exist at runtime_ when the data arrives.

Comment: To sum it up: You have to find put why the server does not send those numbers but empty strings.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Lynx242 you guys were right, had the types wrong on the backend and the server was stripping it out, it would have taken me a month to realize that, Thank You